# sub query from same table mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have questions about sub query. I have table:

| Emp_ID | Date_Entry | Clock_In | Clock_Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 22:01:00 | NUll |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-02 | NULL | 2024-02-02 06:01:05 |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 06:01:00 | 2024-02-03 14:00:20 |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 08:00:00 | 2024-02-04 17:01:05 |

how to query with mysql so when the clock_in >= 22:00:00 then the clock_out is select the next day clock_out like below?:

| Emp_ID | Date_Entry | Clock_In | Clock_Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-01 | 2024-02-01 22:01:00 | 2024-02-02 06:01:05 |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-02 | NULL | 2024-02-02 06:01:05 |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-03 | 2024-02-03 06:01:00 | 2024-02-03 14:00:20 |
| E-0001 | 2024-02-04 | 2024-02-04 08:00:00 | 2024-02-04 17:01:05 |

any help will be appreciated. thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add more sample data than just 2 records?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen hi, there is mistake on the table, I already fix it. thank you for your comment.

Comment: What if Clock_In is 22:01 and Clock_Out is set and it is 23:01? does the value for the next date must be taken nevertheless?

Comment: @Akina Yes, it just take the next day clock_out without the need to calculate the total hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Emp_ID, 
       t1.Date_Entry, 
       t1.Clock_In, 
                -- return next-day time if joined and is not NULL
                -- and current-day time if not joined
       COALESCE(t2.Clock_Out, t1.Clock_Out) Clock_Out
FROM table t1
                      -- join only when time is above 22:00
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON TIME(t1.Clock_In) >= '22:00'
                      -- join only next-day row (if exists)
                  AND t1.Date_Entry + INTERVAL 1 DAY = t2.Date_Entry
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with MySQL 8, the window function `LEAD()` combined with `CASE` clause allows you to retrieve the next *Clock_Out* for cases where *clock_in* is 22:00:00 or later :

```
SELECT Emp_ID, Date_Entry, Clock_In, COALESCE(next_Clock_In, Clock_Out)
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN TIME(Clock_In) >= '22:00' 
            THEN LEAD(Clock_Out) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY Emp_ID ORDER BY Date_Entry) 
       END AS next_Clock_In
  FROM mytable
) AS s;
```

> My solution is based on the assumption that the following day could be
> day +1 or more, @akina's solution is working correctly when the next day is required to be day+1

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0HjSbFOW)

Comment: Will produce wrond output when there are gaps in dates. Also the subquery is obviously excess.

Comment: Hi @Akina, Do you have an example where my query doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/VVaEEXD7 The row for 2024-02-02 is absent. The logic tells that you'd return NULL for 2024-02-01 whereas your query produces a value.